# Activity not restoring data after onDestroy

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onrestoreinstancestate

I am having problems with two ActionBarActivities.
I have my first Activity (WorkoutEditActivity) that starts another Activity (A2) with startActivityForResult from a Fragment inside the WorkoutEditActivity.
When I press the Back Button on the ActionBar from A2 my first Activity gets Destroyed, and saves the Data in onSaveInstanceState and then the Activity gets restarted, but I cannot figure out how to restore the Data.
Here is the relevant Code which does not work:

```
    public class WorkoutEditActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
        int whatShouldBeSaved = -1;

        Workout workout = null;
        ViewPager viewpager;
        ViewFactory factory = new ViewFactory(getSupportFragmentManager());;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.workout_edit_activity);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        viewpager.setAdapter(factory);

        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        if (position == 0) {
                            SettingsFragment.isActivated = true;
                        } else {
                            if (SettingsFragment.isActivated) {
                                SettingsFragment.isActivated = false;
                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                    }
                }
        );

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            whatShouldBeSaved = savedInstanceState.getInt("test", -1);
            if (savedInstanceState.getSerializable("workout") != null){
                setWorkout((Workout) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("workout"));
            }
            Log.d("GOT SAVED DATA", "" + whatShouldBeSaved);
        }
        Log.d("CREATE", "created? " + workout);
        Log.d("CREATE", "created? " + whatShouldBeSaved);
        }

        public void setWorkout(Workout w){
        Log.d("WORKOUT", "had workout " + workout);
        workout = w;
        factory.setWorkout(workout);
        Log.d("WORKOUT", "has workout " + workout);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("RESUME", "resuming act");

        SettingsFragment.isActivated = true;
        //factory.setViewPager(viewpager);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("workout")){
                Log.d("RESUME", "resume has extra");
                setWorkout((Workout) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("workout"));
                whatShouldBeSaved = getIntent().getIntExtra("test", -1);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("RESUME", "extras did not contain workout2");
        }

        Log.d("RESUME", "created? " + workout);
        Log.d("RESUME", "created? " + whatShouldBeSaved);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("ONPAUSE", "called");
        }


        @Override
        public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("START", "starting act");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop(){
        Log.d("STOP", "stopping act");
        super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Log.d("onACTRES", "called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("SAVEINSTANCE", "called");
        savedInstanceState.putInt("test", whatShouldBeSaved);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        Log.d("RESTOREINSTANCE", "called");

        whatShouldBeSaved = savedInstanceState.getInt("test", 1);
        Log.d("GOT SAVE", ""+ whatShouldBeSaved);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.d("RESTOREINSTANCE2", "called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("DESTROY", "onDestroy called");
        Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying " + workout);
        Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying " + whatShouldBeSaved);
        Log.d("DESTROY", "was destroyed");
        //first = true;
        }
    }
```

And here is an excerpt from my Log

```
8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/STOP﹕ stopping act
01-10 13:26:45.110    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/DESTROY﹕ onDestroy called
01-10 13:26:45.110    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/DESTROY﹕ destroying Luffy
01-10 13:26:45.110    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/DESTROY﹕ destroying -1
01-10 13:26:45.110    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/DESTROY﹕ was destroyed
01-10 13:26:45.118    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/onCreate﹕ called
01-10 13:26:45.118    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer V/Monotype﹕ SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = localhost.fitnessoptimizer
01-10 13:26:45.118    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer V/Monotype﹕ Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
01-10 13:26:45.126    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer W/ViewPager﹕ Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1
01-10 13:26:45.126    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/CREATE﹕ created? null
01-10 13:26:45.126    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/CREATE﹕ created? 1
01-10 13:26:45.127    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/START﹕ starting act
01-10 13:26:45.129    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/RESUME﹕ resuming act
01-10 13:26:45.129    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/RESUME﹕ extras did not contain workout2
01-10 13:26:45.129    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/RESUME﹕ created? null
01-10 13:26:45.129    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/RESUME﹕ created? 1
01-10 13:26:45.152    8151-8151/localhost.fitnessoptimizer D/GOT WORKOUT﹕ null
```

onRestoreInstanceState never gets called and onCreates savedInstanceState also does not contain the information.
How can I save or restore the workout (and whatShouldBeSaved, which is actually just a debugging variable)?

PS: I put my code in snippet js tags, because it got quite long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official site [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

> Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) (the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both).

When you press BACK at activity, it will be closed, but not killed. "Killing" could be done by Android system, when app is at background and system need to free some resource temporary.

You need to use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) instead.

Comment: I have tried this and it does work. however i find this is an awful workaround, since i have to save my workout in a json string, and then reload it and parse it from a json string, directly after i put it there. I dont really understand why the activity gets closed, when it just gets restarted after that. why doesnt it just pause and resume?

Comment: @infect please accept and vote answer if it was helpful to solve your current problem

Comment: @infect please read next article http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState, it will give you more details about saving state

Answer (score 0):

*onSaveInstanceState()* only will be called when your activity is destroyed unexpectedly, and it won't be called when activity is destroyed currently. Same with *onRestoreInstanceState()*.
The official site, [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html.)

Comment: Your link says, that the savedInstanceState is in the onCreate parameter, which i tried in my example, but it still does not work!?

Comment: @infect please read carefully all article to understand how does that work, especially Caution blocks